# How to clone project from code.google on windows

Tags: windows, mercurial, google-code

see i need to download code from this page

http://code.google.com/r/steverauny-treeview/source/checkout

which shows to clone

```
hg clone https://code.google.com/r/steverauny-treeview/
```

on my linux machine i have installed `hg`  and then this command work and i got the copy of that project on my machine

but how to get this on windows machine??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Download and install [TortoiseHg](https://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/).

Run the same command:

```
C:\>hg clone https://code.google.com/r/steverauny-treeview TreeView
requesting all changes
adding changesets
adding manifests
adding file changes
added 44 changesets with 255 changes to 111 files
updating to branch default
98 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
```

Answer (score 4):

Use one of the [Windows Mercurial installers.](http://mercurial.selenic.com/downloads)

Comment: @Azahar: Trailing slash on the directory stopped working, apparently